# Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation for HP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Can I install Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation for HP on a Hewlett Packerd SFF PC to run it as a server or does it explicit check for ProLiant BIOS?

Cheers,
Ron

Comment: The best way to answer this question is to try it. Or are there some restrictions that will not allow you to test it?

Comment: I haven't bought it yet. I have to know it before buying... ;-) Test-ISO is also not available on the net. - ron

Comment: Instead of an SFF PC why not use a Microserver?

Comment: My goodness. I'm astounded at the number of questions here that could be quickly answered by a simple phone call to the vendor. Surely Microsoft or HP could answer this for you. Surely they both have sales departments staffed by individuals who can get an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the Foundation R2 media with HP labeled can work in pc machine, only start with dvd media. The right HP server installation way is running the wizard Intelligent Provisioning (Gen8 and Gen9) or SmartStart dvd on Gen7-

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables for someone here to give you a definitive answer. They only way to know would be from experience, but things could have changed since that person tried it out, including BIOS version revisions, etc.

They best thing to do is to ask your HP reseller or inside sales person and get the answer in writing. That way if it doesn't work out you have leverage to get a return processed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I install Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation for HP on a Hewlett Packerd SFF PC

Yes, you can.

> to run it as a server

Yes. If you *should* do that is another story.

> or does it explicit check for ProLiant BIOS?

Depends on your setup media. Generally, you can install Windows FE on a PC.